# IOS app crash with CFNetwork, but can not find the problem

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

can anyone help me with my app crash, here is the crash log, I can not find the problem, thanks very much.

```
Thread 8 name:
Thread 8 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001c852f6f0 objc_retain + 16 (objc-object.h:441)
1   CFNetwork                       0x00000001c99594d0 formEventCallback(__CFReadStream*, unsigned long, void*) + 128 (FormDataStream.c:246)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92bd950 _signalEventSync + 220 (CFStream.c:653)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92bcf0c _cfstream_shared_signalEventSync + 348 (CFStream.c:784)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92aa6c4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1980)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92aa640 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 92 (CFRunLoop.c:2015)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92a9ef8 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 180 (CFRunLoop.c:2051)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92a4bd8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1032 (CFRunLoop.c:2922)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c92a44b8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452 (CFRunLoop.c:3247)
9   CFNetwork                       0x00000001c98cd63c -[__CoreSchedulingSetRunnable runForever] + 216 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1365)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001c9ca5fc0 -[NSThread main] + 72 (NSThread.m:1212)
11  Foundation                      0x00000001c9de2c44 __NSThread__start__ + 1044 (NSThread.m:1175)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c8f1f974 _pthread_body + 132 (pthread.c:857)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c8f1f8d0 _pthread_start + 52 (pthread.c:884)
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001c8f27ddc thread_start + 4
```

Comment: There is more to the crash log than that...

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you need to install fabric or firebase crashlytics in your app. It will help you to debug the crash issue.

Here is the link for fabric:   https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install